# How can I convert uploaded files (e.g. Excel, Word, PDF) from Apple Format to Windows when uploading to a web application?

Tags: c#, angular, azure, ipad

I am the developer and support person for a website with an Angular 5 UI and C#/WebAPI back end. The site is hosted in Azure.

The main users use the site on their iPads. They can submit "requests", and can optionally attach files (of any format) to these requests.

The uploading works fine, but when the back-office team (which uses Windows PCs) tries to download these attachments, they experience errors because the files are in Apple format, not in Windows format.

Note that if the files are uploaded using a PC, then there is no problem with the conversion.

Is there a way to capture the "source OS", and if the "source OS" is Apple, then the file is converted to Windows when the "destination OS" is Windows? Is there software that can do this type of conversion on the server side, without involvement from an end-user?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is "apple format"?

Comment: I used the term "apple format" to mean how the given files (pdf, office, or whatever) are stored on Apple computers and devices, most notably the iPad.

Comment: office and pdf files wouldn't be a problem. this is way too broad - you have to look at your requirements

Comment: To narrow it down to one file type (Excel), I'm getting the following message when I try to open an xlsx file that was uploaded from an iPad and then downloaded from the web app to a PC:

"Excel cannot open the file because the extension is not valid verify that the file is not corrupted..."

I assumed that this was due to some incompatibility between Excel files between Mac and PC, but perhaps that's not the case. What might this be indicative of?